# Stubbing Ajax requests in Cucumber / Capybara / Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, tdd, cucumber, capybara

In my Rails 3.2 project, I send an occasional http request to `http://jsonip.com` from Javascript. But when running Cucumber with the `@javascript` tag, the request gets sent very frequently. This is obviously very undesirable and I would like to stub such requests. Now, I thought I could use the `stub_request` from `webmock` for this, like so:

```
Before do
  stub_request(:any, /.*jsonip.*/).to_return(:body => '{"ip":"24.104.73.2","about":"/about"}')
end
```

but even with this in place, `jsonip` gets called from Javascript. And so I found that `webmock` does not actually stub Ajax request (at least not with the above `stub_request` statement).

What is the right way to stub Ajax request in a Cucumber / Capybara / Selenium setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to do it is to change url or disable request depending on the environment application is run.

You can't stub this request from test side because this request is made by *browser* not by your application.

Also as temporary solution or solution for CI server you can disable this url in hosts file.

Comment: Hmmm, yes... I was afraid of that. I got it to work now by simply generating a Javascript variable that holds 0 when the Rails environment is development, 1 when it is test and 2 when it is production. I then prevent the Ajax call to the external service when the variable equals 1. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works. Thanks, Iafonov.

Answer (score 6):

You can use puffing-billy https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy for that purpose. I'm using it to mock JSONP calls to Recurly in my app.

Answer (score 4):

Capybara isn't aware of any requests stubbed via webmock as the requests are coming from capybara-webkit or firefox.

This thoughtbot article will guide you through it:
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-capybara-to-test-javascript-that-makes-http